# The purpose of getBaseTag() and <base> in Plone

Tags: html, plone

Plone `main_template` includes `<base>` tag which is generated by `parts/omelette/Products/CMFDefault/skins/zpt_content/getBaseTag.pt.

It points to the absolute URL of the current content item. If the content item has a cover page (default content item) then it points to here.

Settings base tag to different than the current windows location URL breaks some `<a href="#fragment">` inner-page navigation behavior: setting / clicking the fragment causes the page reload from the `<base>` URL.

- What is the reason Plone sets `<base>` tag?
- Is it safe to get rid of it? What could potentially break?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because Plone items are not files on a disk, and because we can use acquisition in Plone, any piece of HTML can be rendered via different URLs. Via acquisition, it could be almost anything for example, but folderish items can be rendered both with and without a trailing slash.

The browser bases relative URLs within a page on the current page URL, unless a `<base />` tag is present, in which case any relative URLs on the page are made absolute relative to that URL instead.

Remove the tag at your own peril; there are *always* more relative URLs to contend with than you could hope to eliminate.

Comment: aaaaaarfggsadlkfgjsjbgakljbasdf ZPublisher.insertBase, acquisition, life. In this order. It's pretty impossible to remove.

Answer (score 1):

I remember @davisagli once mentioning that `<base />` tag is needed on password reset page validations.